# How to format and print float numbers on iOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I would like to create a formatted output of a floating point number with correct localization on Cocoa-Touch. The output should be equivalent to that of `printf("%<a>.<b>f", n)`, where `<a>` is the total number of digits and `<f>` is the maximum number of fractional digits.

**Setup of `NSNumberFormatter` with `<a>=6` and `<f>=2`**: (Platform is iOS 5.1 SDK, Xcode 4.3.3 and the iPhone Simulator 5.1)

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[nf setPaddingCharacter:@" "];
[nf setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
[nf setLocale:[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]];
[nf setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[nf setMaximumSignificantDigits:6];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[nf setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
NSLog(@"Test: %@", [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.64324897]]);
```

**Expected output** (with German locale): `Test:   2,64`

**Observed output** (with German locale): `Test: 2,64324`

**Other observations**:
I have tried to use different values for the fraction digits, e.g. `[nf setMaximumFractionDigits:4]` or `[nf setMaximumFractionDigits:0]`. The result is unchanged, it appears that the fraction digits are ignored. Changing the locale to US only changes the `,` to a `.`, not the number of fraction digits.

**Question**: How can I translate the `printf`-format string correctly to an `NSNumberFormatter`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ryan is not totally wrong. Use the `localizedStringWithFormat` method:

**using objective-c**

```
NSNumber *yourNumber = [nf numberFromString:yourString];
//to create the formatted NSNumber object

NSString *yourString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.2F", yourNumber];
//to create the localized output
```

**using SWIFT 3**

```
let yourString: String
yourString = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.2F", yourDoubleNumber) //no need for NSNumber Object
```

A little bit late but it still might help. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what it needs to do! Thank you, even a late answer is appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome! I had some difficulties with localization as well. Good luck!

Comment: Magic. And there I was, writing NSNumber categories... when all I needed was already there, neat and simple. This is the kind of little things that makes us so fond of Apple.